# How should script output be formatted for Ansible reporting?

Tags: ansible

I'm using Ansible v1.3 to run a bash script on a group of servers.  I'm trying to get my output to work with what Ansible is expecting to format the output correctly but I'm missing something.

I've read somewhere (can't find the link!) that if script output is formatted as JSON, Ansible will pick it up and include it in the output.

So in the script, the very last thing I do is this:

```
cat <<EOF
{
    "value" : $value
}
EOF
```

I call my script like this:

```
ansible target_hosts -m script -a script.sh
```

And the output I get is like this:

```
X.X.X.X | success >> {
    "rc": 0,
    "stderr": "",
    "stdout": "value=96\r\n"
}
```

I'm expecting to see something like this:

```
X.X.X.X | success >> {
    "rc": 0,
    "stderr": "",
    "stdout": "",
    "value": "96"
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are running your module as a script. Create a `library` folder and put your script there. After that, you can run your script with:

```
ansible target_hosts -m script.sh
```

I case of doubt, take a look at: http://jpmens.net/2012/07/05/shell-scripts-as-ansible-modules/

**Note**: Don't forget to include a `#!/bin/bash` in the top of the file, or ansible will fail with a message like `target_host | FAILED => module is missing interpreter line`

Comment: Thanks. Also, ansible documents this too now, http://docs.ansible.com/developing_modules.html